# Add support for other robots to CRAM?

Tags: ros, cram

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any documentation for how to add support for new robots to CRAM? I have all the tutorials and examples working with the default PR2 robot, but I'd like to use the system with a UR5.

We have the UR5 set up with MoveIt, so the necessary URDFs, SRDFs, and other config files for that piece should already exist. I'm just looking for info on which additional pieces are needed to use basic motion planning functionality and query the state of the robot from within CRAM (i.e. the functionality that's demonstrated in [this tutorial](http://cram-project.org/tutorials/intermediate/moveit))

I've dug around the CRAM documentation quite a bit and haven't found anything relevant. A link to instructions or even just some quick pointers on which parts of the cram_pr2 package I'd need to modify would be much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228756/add-support-for-other-robots-to-cram?/) by [abestick](https://answers.ros.org/users/26180/abestick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Followup for those interested: turns out this wasn't nearly as difficult as I'd anticipated. Once the robot is working in MoveIt, just replace the line

```
roslaunch pr2_moveit_config demo.launch
```

in the tutorial with the corresponding command to launch the move_group node for your robot. Everything else just works - you should be able to query the robot's joint states and plan/execute motions.

Not sure what higher level planning/control functionality might need to be changed or reimplemented to make other tutorials work with a new robot, but the basics work with only the above.

---

Originally posted by [abestick](https://answers.ros.org/users/26180/abestick/) with karma: 18 on 2016-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0